# Is overheating a sign that I need a new CPU?

Tags: laptop, cpu, temperature, overheating

I have an HP Envy laptop. A while ago my CPU fan started dying, and the whole side of the laptop would heat up. I didn't use an application to check the CPU temperature, but I never experienced anything that would indicate the CPU was overheating. I took it into a repair shop, and they replaced the CPU fan.

Now, the laptop is cool but Core Temp says the CPU is always hot. Several times it got too hot and everything ground to a halt until it cooled down.

They replaced the heatsink, but that did nothing. They're telling me it must be a bad CPU and I need to get a new one. I haven't heard of CPUs overheating because they've gone bad, but I'm not a hardware-savvy person at all. Is it likely this is actually causing the problem?

Comment: The problem can also be a weak PSU. I would also verify the verdict at another repair shop.

Comment: Is the new fan working properly?

Comment: @harrymc I'll update the question with any relevant information I get.

Comment: @Moab It blows air out and keeps the rest of the laptop cool. The CPU isn't being cooled enough, but I don't think it's the fan's fault.

Comment: There isn’t any situation I can think of where a working CPU would be at fault for overheating. It most likely is that they didn’t reseat the heatsink to the CPU properly. Laptop CPUs are tiny and the surface area that mates with the heat sink is small. If anything is tweaked so that it doesn’t lay perfectly flat and mated with the CPU, it’s going to overheat. Someone with sufficient skills and experience can fix that. But it absolutely isn’t a bad CPU.